# Apache Tiles fails with error, but only when logging level set greater than INFO?

Tags: java, apache, apache-tiles

We have a Tomcat application that runs on Tomcat 7.0.55 and uses Apache Tiles 2.1.4.

Our Apache Tiles setup works fine with our Log4j logging set to INFO or anything greater (WARN or ERROR).   But with it set to DEBUG, TRACE or ALL, I get this error on Tomcat startup and the startup completely fails.

**EDIT:**  If this was happening all the time I would understand it and not post here.   This is an odd, Stackoverflow-worthy problem for two reasons:

1)  We're not using Portlets **at all**.  There shouldn't be any calls to Portlet code anywhere.
2)  As a corollary to (1), the app **runs fine** when the logging level is set lower than DEBUG.   This error only happens when logging is set to DEBUG, TRACE or ALL.

```
2015-03-27 07:18:44,453 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tiles.context.AbstractTilesApplicationContextFactory - Initializing Tiles2 application context. . .
2015-03-27 07:18:44,460 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tiles.context.AbstractTilesApplicationContextFactory - Finished initializing Tiles2 application context.
2015-03-27 07:18:44,472 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tiles.factory.TilesContainerFactory - Initializing Tiles2 container. . .
2015-03-27 07:18:44,538 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tilesConfigurer' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.portle
t.context.NotAPortletEnvironmentException: Cannot access portlet classes
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4992)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5490)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1880)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.tiles.portlet.context.NotAPortletEnvironmentException: Cannot access portlet classes
        at org.apache.tiles.portlet.context.PortletTilesRequestContextFactory.<init>(PortletTilesRequestContextFactory.java:71)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:438)
        at org.apache.tiles.context.ChainedTilesRequestContextFactory.init(ChainedTilesRequestContextFactory.java:100)
        at org.apache.tiles.factory.TilesContainerFactory.storeContainerDependencies(TilesContainerFactory.java:429)
        at org.apache.tiles.factory.TilesContainerFactory.initializeContainer(TilesContainerFactory.java:368)
        at org.apache.tiles.factory.TilesContainerFactory.createTilesContainer(TilesContainerFactory.java:287)
        at org.apache.tiles.factory.TilesContainerFactory.createContainer(TilesContainerFactory.java:231)
        at org.apache.tiles.startup.BasicTilesInitializer.createContainer(BasicTilesInitializer.java:117)
        at org.apache.tiles.startup.BasicTilesInitializer.initialize(BasicTilesInitializer.java:53)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer.afterPropertiesSet(TilesConfigurer.java:339)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/portlet/PortletRequest
        at org.apache.tiles.portlet.context.PortletTilesRequestContextFactory.<init>(PortletTilesRequestContextFactory.java:66)
        ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.portlet.PortletRequest
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
        ... 41 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Caused by: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/portlet/PortletRequest`

`NoClassDefFoundError` is related to a missing class file at runtime which is available at compile time. In your case tomcat. If you are using maven, ensure that your dependency scope covers runtime. Your lib directory in your war should have the jar. Potentially the following:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.portlet/portlet-api/2.0

but it appears to be available at compile time, so check there first.

If this jar dependency should be at an application server level, it will need to go in the `/lib/ext` tomcat folder.

Edit (response to comment 1): It seems apache tiles is using it under the hood, even to verify that portlets are not required. As the code requires it, it is insisting on it. Please check your compilation to see if it has the jar available to it, because if it does, it needs it at runtime.

2015-03-27 07:18:44,538 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tilesConfigurer' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.portle
t.context.NotAPortletEnvironmentException: Cannot access portlet classes

Caused by: org.apache.tiles.portlet.context.NotAPortletEnvironmentException: Cannot access portlet classes
        at org.apache.tiles.portlet.context.PortletTilesRequestContextFactory.(PortletTilesRequestContextFactory.java:71)

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/portlet/PortletRequest
        at org.apache.tiles.portlet.context.PortletTilesRequestContextFactory.(PortletTilesRequestContextFactory.java:66)

Comment: The trouble is, that we're not using Portlets at all, and the app works fine when the logging is set lower.   I'll edit the question to add this bit of information - good catch.

Comment: See edit, not sure about the logging, but this is very suprising that it has a difference based on logging. So, the app works fine with tiles functionality, or is it quiet failing? What log files is it appending to? Is there a chance that the logging configuration changes causes issues not to be logged, rather than them not happening?

Comment: With the logging level set to "WARN", "INFO" or "ERROR" the application works fine.   it fails hard with a level of "ERROR" as indicated in the trace, so there's really no way it could be silently failing.   The error appears in the console and stops the startup dead cold, so there's really nothing to check the log files for.  I agree that it's very strange that the difference is based on logging level, I have not seen that before.